# How to show multiple fields in combobox using linq in C# Windows form?

Tags: c#, linq, combobox

I want to show at least two column like FirstName and Lastname as DisplayMember and username as ValueMember from my Sql database. I tried like this but not working. It's working only with one field, but not if I want to show both Firstname and Lastname.

```
public void Employees()
{
            db = new DbEntities();


            var emp = (from u in db.Users
                        select u).ToList(); 
            cmbEmployee.DisplayMember =  "FirstName" +" " + " LastName";
            cmbEmployee.ValueMember = "UserName";
            cmbEmployee.DataSource = emp;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join firstname and lastname in you linq query:

```
var emp = db.Users.Select(x=> $"{x.FirstName} {x.LastName}").ToList(); 
cmbEmployee.DataSource = emp;
```

**Edit** (considering your comment):

```
var emp = db.Users.Select(x=> new { 
               Display = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
               Value = x.UserName}).ToList(); 
cmbEmployee.DisplayMember =  "Display";
cmbEmployee.ValueMember = "Value";
cmbEmployee.DataSource = emp;
```

Comment: Mobayen thenk you for response. but  Iget error System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method . I get this error in the first row db.users.select...... How ca nO solve this problem? The second questoin is how to formulate then DisplayMember and ValueMember? Thank you

Comment: @HelenTekie, may be your c# version is old, try it like this: `var emp = db.Users.Select(x=> x.FirstName + " " +x.LastName).ToList();`

Comment: Mobayen , thank you now Firstname and lastname displaying but even the yare as value. But I want username as value. I mean FirstName and LastName as DisplayMember and Username as ValueMember. Right now even ValeMember is FirstName and LastName. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the `User` class you have two options:

1) Override the `ToString` method and **don't** specify a `DisplayMember`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return FirstName + " " + LastName;
}
```

2) Provide a property (e.g `FirstAndLast`) and set that as your `DisplayMember`:

```
public string FirstAndLast { get => FirstName + " " + LastName; }
```